# How to make a WebView stub: Web page not available?

Tags: java, android

Tell me please, how to make a WebView stub: browser page (inverted android robot) - *“The web page at www.example.com could not be loaded because: ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED“* when the device don't have Internet connection?

For example, received to local custom HTML page with a notification: no internet or simple toast.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly u r trying, you want a custom web page to appear when internet is broken?

Comment: How can your server load a page if it's disconnected? Seems strange to me

Comment: @ankuruniyal yes

Comment: @HamzaInce local page with app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly create one HTML page 'ErrorPage.html' in asset folder for Error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Error Received</title>
</head>
<body>
   <center>
        <h1>Error Received</h1>
        <p>We are getting issue. Please check your internet connection and try again! 
        </p>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can do override WebViewClient callback 'onReceivedError':

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here - This is optional
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)  {
         webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ErrorPage.html");
   }
});
```

Comment: what should be in 'onPageFinished', where comment?

Comment: and how to do instead html page - simple toast?

Comment: Here you can do that action which you want after finish the page like if you initiated progress bar or dialog, you can dismiss here. But in your case it does't required. You can remove this method.

Comment: Inside onReceivedError method, you can use simple toast instead of Error html page.

Comment: where is this asset folder (android_asset)?